# Is moving a file safer than deleting it if you want to remove all traces of it?

Tags: security, filesystems, delete-file, erase

I recently accidentally called "rm -rf *" on a directory an deleted some files that I needed. However, I was able to recover most of them using photorec. Apparently, "deleting" a file just removes references to said file and is not truly deleted until it is overwritten by something else.

So if I wanted to remove the file completely, couldn't I just execute

```
mv myfile.txt /temp/myfile.txt
```

(or move to external storage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. that won't help either.

A move when going between file systems is really still just a "copy + rm" internally. The original storage location of the file on the "source" media is still there, just marked as available. A moving WITHIN a file system doesn't touch the file bytes at all, it just updates the bookkeeping to say "file X is now in location Y".

To truly wipe a file, you must overwriteall of its bytes. And yet again, technology gets in the way of that - if you're using a solid state storage medium, there is a VERY high chance that writing 'garbage' to the file won't touch the actual transistors the file's stored in, but actually get written somewhere completely different.

For magnetic media, repeated overwriting with alternating 0x00, 0xFF, and random bytes will eventually totally nuke the file. For SSD/flash systems, it either has to offer a "secure erase" option, or you have to smash the chips into dust. For optical media, it's even more complicated. -r media cannot be erased, only destroyed. for -rw, I don't know how many repeated-write cycles are required to truly erase the bits.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the Linux command `shred`, which overwrites the target file multiple times before deleting it completely, which makes it 'impossible' to recover the file.

You can read a bit about the shred command [here](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_shred.htm).

Just moving the  file does not cover you for good, if you moved it to external storage, the local version of the file is deleted just as it is with the `rm` command.

Answer (score 1):

No (and not just because moving it somewhere else on your computer is not removing it from the computer).  The way to completely remove a file is to completely overwrite the space on the disk where it resided.  The linux command `shred` will accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no, in most file systems you can't guarantee that a file is overwritten without going very low level. Removing a file and/or moving it will only change the pointer to the file, not the files existence in the file system in any way. Even the linux command *shred* won't guarantee a file's removal in many file systems since it assumes files are overwritten in place.

On SSDs, it's even more likely that your data stays there for a long time, since even if the file system would attempt to overwrite blocks, the SSD will remap to write to a new block (erasing takes a lot of time, if it wrote in place things would be very slow)

In the end, with modern file systems and disks, the best chance you have to have files stored securely is to keep them encrypted to begin with. If they're stored anywhere in clear text, they can be *very* hard to remove, and recovering an encrypted file from disk (or a backup for that matter) won't be much use to anyone without the encryption key.